# Adding new Entity related to another specific one on Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have related two related entities: Magazine and Issue with a OneToMany relationship.
How can I create a form to add a new Issue entity related to a specific Magazine?

When I create a form in the controller, calling it from the form class to add an Issue, how can I pass it a pre-established value for some of its fields?

I know this have to be easy, but I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple options:

## Hidden field:

You could add a hidden field to your `FormType` and pass e.g. the `Magazine ID` like that. You can checkout [this tutorial](http://lrotherfield.com/blog/symfony2-forms-entity-as-hidden-field/) as an example.

In detail it should look like this in your `FormType`:

```
$builder->add('magazine', 'entity' /*, more options... */);
```

And in your `Controller`:

```
$magazine = // get Your magazine here...
$issue = new Issue();
$issue->setMagazine($magazine);
$form = $this->createForm(new YourFormType(), $issue);
```

## In the route:

You could simply generate a route like this: `/magazines/{magazine_id}/issues/add`
This would give you the `Magazine` entity in your *Controller Action* like so:

```
public function addAction($magazineId)
{
    $magazine = // get by $magazineId
    // generate your issue form and stuff

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $issue->setMagazine($magazine);
    }
}
```

And you could work from there on.

Comment: Thanks, this solved It, I hadn't thought of setting some fields before calling the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can approach your problem in two separate ways.

1 -  **Routes** : Did you setup a different route for adding an issue to each magazine?

In your controller you can do something like:

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
    ...
    $magazine = $this->getManager()
                     ->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Magazine')
                     ->findOneBy($magazineId); // /{magazineId}/issue/new
    ...
    $issue->setMagazine($magazine);
    $em->persist($issue);
    ...
}
```

Also you can read the docs for [route parameters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#routing-with-placeholders).

2 - **Single Form**: If you add a new issue in the same route `/issue/new`

When adding your `Issue` fields to the `$formBuilder` add a dropdown list to asign the `Magazine`

```
$builder->add('magazine', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'BundleNamespace:Magazine',
    //If your class does not have a __toString() method add below
    'property' => 'title',
));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind Magazine entity to the new Issue entity, you will have to add
a field with **entity type** in your form (with the formBuilder).

```
$builder->add('magazine', 'entity', array(
'class' => 'AcmeBundle:Magazine',
'property' => 'title'));
```

See the [doc about entity field in form](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html).